# Create Multi-Index from Index and Column

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, merge, multi-index

I have a multiIndex dataframe that I am merging with another multiIndex dataframe and it merged successfully but now it only has one Index?

```
climate_df2.index.names
Out[79]: FrozenList(['key', 'Y'])

fileformat_df.index.names
Out[80]: FrozenList(['key', 'Y'])

climate_df3 = pd.merge(climate_df2.reset_index(), fileformat_df.reset_index(),
                   on = ["key","Y"], how = "inner").set_index("key","Y")

climate_df3.index.names
Out[81]: FrozenList(['key'])

climate_df3.columns
Out[82]: Index(['Y', 'DatasetName', 'Organization', 'URL', 'FileFormat'], dtype='object')
```

But now the former Index "Y" is a column in the merged dataframe. So I would either like to have the merged DF return both indexes in the first place, or just add the column "Y" to the merged dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out how to "fix" it:

```
climate_df3.set_index(["Y"], append = True)
```

I am still not sure why "Y" ended up in the columns but this puts it back in the MultiIndex.